# Error importing numpy on IDLE on Mac

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I am using a mac and when I try to import numpy on IDLE, then it shows this:

```
File "/Users/muchen/Desktop/Pelt implementation/pymrfbp-1.12/examples/numpy/__init__.py", line 170, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
    its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
    your python interpreter from there.
```

I know it can be a duplicate question as someone asked this before but I didn't get a working solution on my Mac. I hope for a step-by-step guide. Another question is do I need to install numpy? I just downloaded and unzipped, but how can I install it on a Mac? I also need a step-by-step guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to first part of your question is here

```
you should not try to import numpy from
its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
your python interpreter from there.
```

Just launch interpreter from any other location. For example, from `$HOME/myproject` folder.

The easiest way to install numpy is to use `pip`. Just type in terminal

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: Thanks! I did so, but then I got another error: `ImportError: No module named 'numpy.linalg'`. Why?

Comment: @Ian Try to install numpy with `pip` as I wrote in my answer

Comment: I did it again and it shows `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: or can you tell me how to uninstall and I may try it again

Comment: @Ian You could uninstall it with `pip uninstall numpy`. Could you add to you post results of commands `which python` and `which idle` from terminal?

Comment: @Ian Python2.7 is default Mac python. Looks like you launch `idle` for Python3.5.1 and in it `numpy` doesn't installed.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!

Comment: @Ian You are welcome) If my answer/comments were helpful you could upvote/mark as right answer)